# How bind keys to a specific snippet in yasnippet folder?

Tags: elisp, key-bindings, yasnippet

Let's say I have a `yasnippet` snippet called `foobar` and I have configured it to work it with `company-mode` (which is not relevant here). Now each time I needed to type `foobar` I would select it from completion popup to expand `yasnippet`.

But now I would like to bind this `yasnippet` insertion action to a key.

I found the `yas/insert-snippet` function. But then I need to select the corresponding snippet.

I'm looking for a configuration like below to insert the `foobar` snippet.

```el
(global-set-key "C-b" yas/insert-snippet "foobar") ;; PSEUDO CODE
```

Any suggestions? It would be really appreciated.

Comment: Snippets can contain a line that looks like this:  `# binding: C-I z`  If you place the snippet inside a folder with the mode-name within the main snippet directory, the keyboard shortcut will work in that major-mode if yasnippet is configured correctly.  That method can also be used to execute `elisp` code within the snippet (if applicable) so long as it is wrapped in back-ticks.  I access all my snippets like that, or by using a right click pop-up mouse menu that I have customized to read all available snippets for a given mode.  **NOTE**:  This `# binding` method will hijack the shortcut.

Comment: Here is a link to the yasnippet manual that describes direct binding:  https://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-2-6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, lawlist! It's appreciated. But I see two little issues here: 
- I use evil. I noticed it will work when you're in insert mode of Evil. When you're currently in normal mode, the keybinding will do nothing. - - I would like to bind it to the key `gl` with keychord. So I might need a solution in Elisp, because yasnippet doesn't know the keys `gl`.

Comment: @lawlist that link doesn't seem to be working. Updated one - https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org67f4e69 HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `# binding:` header [documented in the manual](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-2-6) is the official method to do this. It's implemented using `emulation-mode-map-alists` which means it will override any other major or minor mode keybindings, except for packages which also use `emulation-mode-map-alists`, typically emulation packages like Evil.

> I noticed it will work when you're in insert mode of Evil.  When you're currently in normal mode, the keybinding will do nothing. -- I would like to bind it to the key `gl` with keychord.

You could use something like:

```el
(defun exand-yasnippet-foobar ()
  "Expand the yasnippet named `foobar'."
  (interactive)
  (yas-expand-snippet (yas-lookup-snippet "foobar")))
```

And then bind `expand-yasnippet-foobar` to some key in whatever keymap you like. Make sure your snippet includes a `# name: foobar` header.

---

`yas-lookup-snippet` was [added](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/commit/e8934ce816ac0f6fdfce06b7e3fabb1fe6bf1190) to yasnippet on August 3rd, 2015. For older versions it can be defined as

```el
(defun yas-lookup-snippet (name &optional _mode noerror)
  (let* ((yas-choose-tables-first nil)  ; avoid prompts
         (yas-choose-keys-first nil)
         (snippet (cl-find name (yas--all-templates
                                 (yas--get-snippet-tables))
                           :key #'yas--template-name :test #'string=)))
    (cond
     (snippet (yas--template-content snippet))
     (noerror nil)
     (t (error "No snippet named: %s" NAME)))))
```

Comment: I know I'm late with my comment, but I saw I never thanked you for your solution. Sorry for the delay, but thank you for your support! It's really appreciated!