# Yasnippet: How to create multiple snippet key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, yasnippet

I have a `yasnippet` with `# binding: TAB f o o` in the header.  This is processed by the `yasnippet` library as `9 102 111 111`.  With respect to a keymap of a major-mode, both `\C-i` and `(kbd "TAB")` are converted to the number 9 when said keymap is set up.  However, both `[(tab)]` and `(kbd "<tab>")` are converted to `tab` when the the major-mode keymap is set up.

A yasnippet with a key binding in the header consisting of `TAB f o o` will **not** trump/supersede a major-mode keybinding of `[(tab)]` or `(kbd "<tab>")`.

**Q**:   How can I set up two (2) different `yasnippet` header keybindings to cover both situations that may exist in a particular major-mode; i.e., a major-mode key binding that uses a number 9 and also a key binding that uses a `tab`?

Here is a link to a related thread, which is interesting, but does not go as far as I would like in order to be able to answer this question:  [What is the difference between TAB and <tab>?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/what-is-the-difference-between-tab-and-tab)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12552/how-bind-keys-to-a-specific-snippet-in-yasnippet-folder may of interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yas--read-keybinding` is a helper function that processes the keybinding contained within the heading of each snippet, and said function calls `read-kbd-macro`.  The following are the results of the four possibilities mentioned in question above:

1. `(read-kbd-macro "TAB" 'vector)` => [9]
2. `(read-kbd-macro "[(tab)]" 'vector)` => [91 40 116 97 98 41 93]
3. `(read-kbd-macro "<tab>" 'vector)` => [tab]
4. `(read-kbd-macro "\C-i" 'vector)` => [] => nothing in between the matching square brackets

There are a variety of possibilities to resolve the issue described in the question above, but creating multiple bindings in the snippet itself would require rewiring the innards of the `yasnippet.el` library.

We can probably all agree that writing virtually duplicate snippets, with the only difference being the keybinding, is not a good solution.

I observed that once a snippet keybinding of `9` trumps a major-mode keybinding, other snippets with a variation of `tab` will follow suit.  I.e., it is possible to have some snippets with a `9` and some snippets with a `tab` and the combination is sufficient trump either form in the major-mode keybinding.  [Although not tried, based on the same rationale, it is probably possible to define both a `9` and a `tab` in the major-mode keybinding and then either one of them appearing in a snippet would be sufficient to trump.]

**CONCLUSION**:

If the major-mode uses `\C-i` or `(kbd "TAB")`, then the snippet should use `TAB`.

If the major-mode uses `[(tab)]` or `(kbd "<tab>")`, then the snippet should use `<tab>`.

Or, try defining both forms in the major-mode keybindings as discussed hereinabove and use either `TAB` or `<tab>` in the snippet.